# MySQL: use "IF NOT IN" in procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to check `class` using MySQL procedure, but the following procedure always returns 0:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `validate_class`(IN `class` INT)
BEGIN
    if(class NOT IN  ('A','B','E') ) then    
         select 1;
    else
         select 0;
    end if;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

call test:

```
call validate_class('G'); //return 0
call validate_class('A'); //return 0
```

It should return `1` when class isn't (`A` and `B` and `E`), any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have implicit conversions `CHAR` -> `INT` -> `CHAR`.

Change parameter datatype:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `validate_class`(IN `class` CHAR(1))
BEGIN
    if(class NOT IN  ('A','B','E') ) then    
         select 1;
    else
         select 0;
    end if;
END
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27bc7/1/0)**</kbd>